# How to replace a NUL character(\x00) in a string in Erlang?

Tags: regex, erlang

When i use re:replace like this, the NUL character will not be replaced but the Replacement will insert before every character:

```
1> S = [97, 0, 98].
[97,0,98]
2> R = re:replace(S, "\x00", " ", [global, {return, list}]).
[32,97,32,0,32,98,32]
```

I expect **R** to be **[97, 32, 98]**. What's wrong with this expression? How to replace a NUL character(\x00) in a string in Erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're replacing a single character with another single character, `lists:map` might be simpler:

```
R = lists:map(fun(0) -> 32; (C) -> C end, S).
```

I suspect that the behaviour of `re:replace` is because it calls the PCRE library, which somehow doesn't handle strings with NUL characters in them.  The result you get is what you'd expect if you tried to replace the empty string with a space globally.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE can operate on binary data (i.e. with embedded null characters).  However, the regular expression pattern you pass to PCRE must be a string.  When you say "\x00" in Erlang, that's like [0], which embeds a null byte into the regular expression string.  Thus as far as PCRE is concerned, you just told it the pattern it should be using is an empty string, which matches everything.

Fortunately this is easy to handle with PCRE.  PCRE itself understands \x notation, meaning if you pass it \x00, it will match null bytes.  Since a backslash is special to Erlang, you must escape it: "\\x00".

```
1> S = [97, 0, 98].
[97,0,98]
2> R = re:replace(S, "\\x00", " ", [global, {return, list}]).
"a b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are what PCRE understands, specifically, the C concept of strings where 0 is treated as a terminator. Lists are all Erlang understands, "strings" being lists with members drawn from a peculiar set of values.

The PCRE library appears to be treating your regex as meaning "between every string" and your list as a list of strings, not characters. So it effectively splits your list with your provided value, which isn't what you intended. legoscia's solution (treating the input as a list, not as a "string") is probably the most robust option.